# IOS- Facebook file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice error

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to integrate Facebook SDK v4.8 in my app. Everything works fine for `arm64` devices but when I enable support for `armv7s` or `armv7`, I am getting this error:

```
file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It point towards `FBSDKLoginKit.framework`.
Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for the `armv7s` has been removed in v4.6.0 of the Facebook iOS SDK back in September of this year, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x#4_6_0_modified